# Using Maven and Spring and Apache Spark in IntelliJ cause error

Tags: java, spring, maven, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I have a Maven Spring projects that works fine without any error when I run this in terminal:

```
java -jar myPro.jar
```

But when I add spark dependency in `pom.xml`, this error appears:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.test.myProject.myMainClass
```

My `pom.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>myProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <!--<packaging>war</packaging>-->

    <name>SUSAHCRUDNIE</name>
    <description>Spring Boot Employee Application</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>8.0.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.4</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.test.myProject.myMainClass</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <index>true</index>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.test.myProject.myMainClass</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The dependency which is cause that error is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

The myMainClass is:

```
package com.test.myProject;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource("application.properties")
public class myMainClass{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(myMainClass.class, args);
    }
}
```

In stackoverflow, there are a lot of questions about not finding main class, and I tested almost all of them but does not help, Of course the other questions are not about not finding main class after adding spark dependency. So be sure that, this question is not duplicate.

After a long time searching and testing I could not solve it!

Comment: Check that your jar contains your main class in correct folder. jar files are simple zip archive you can open it same way you open zip, or rename it to zip and open it as usual folder.

Comment: @talex thanks for your asnwer. There is at `com\test\myProject\myMainClass.class`, is it right?

Comment: Yes. Check if it there. If it is there check content of manifest file in `META-INF\MANIFEST.MF`.

Comment: @talex this file has 2 lines. First line is `Manifest-Version: 1.0` and second line is `Main-Class: com.test.myProject.myMainClass`.

Comment: Google doesn't know what "com.sahabpardaz.ipdrquerying.IPDRQuerying" and I have no idea where it com from.

Comment: First do not mix spring versions ...cause the parent uses 1.5.4.RELEASE where as the spring-boot-maven-plugin uses 2.1.0.RELEASE. Furthermore if you working with Spring Boot you don't use maven-assembly-plugin nor maven-jar-plugin...just use spring-boot-maven-plugin...nothing else...

Comment: @talex sorry "com.sahabpardaz.ipdrquerying.IPDRQuerying" was in my clipboard, and when I pasted, I quickly edited the comment.

Comment: @khmarbaise thank you, I used maven-assembly-plugin to make a fat jar. So without that, how can I make a fat jar?

Comment: It is built by spring-boot-maven-plugin...you neither need maven-assembly-plugin nor maven-jar-plugin just keep spring-boot-maven-plugin in your configuration (of course other dependencies you are using)...and than simply `mvn clean package` that's it...

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks again, can you tell me where can I execute `mvn clean package`?

Comment: Plain command line...

Comment: @khmarbaise please consider that I have run my jar with all dependencies before adding Spark. So my created fat jar was OK at before.

Comment: I've had errors adding Spark dependency to my projects on the Eclipse-based Spring Tool Suite (STS) bundle. I haven't had that issue on regular Eclipse Neon. Not sure if its an IDE or Spark dependency issue. Did you try other IDEs?

Comment: @khmarbaise thank you very much, I can make the jar file without any problem with `mvn clean package`.

Comment: @Nikhil No I did not try other IDEs, but after using `mvn clean package` the problem is solved.

Comment: Great. Please add that answer and select it as the right answer! It would be helpful to others!

Comment: @Nikhil of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @khmarbaise said, I have changed the pom.xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>myProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <!--<packaging>war</packaging>-->

    <name>SUSAHCRUDNIE</name>
    <description>Spring Boot Employee Application</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>8.0.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.4</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And by going to the project folder and using `mvn clean package` in it, the problem was solved.